# Has there been a change in the way Sonarqube 9.9 recalculates the metric for lines of code?

Tags: sonarqube

There was a recent upgrade to Sonarqube 9.9 LTS where I work and we noticed that a particular project which is Angular and contains Javascript, Typescript, HTML, and CSS source files had shown a nearly 50% drop in the calculated metric for lines of code. At the same time, the number of total lines remained relatively the same before and after the upgrade. I can only speculate on what accounts for this sudden drop but I am not entirely sure why the calculation changed. Anyone else notice this behavior?